# unable to store json in single line inside azure blob storage using azure function

Tags: json.net, azure-functions

I have a requirement to store json in a single line(without any formatting) inside a blob storage file. I am using azure function with Newtonsoft.JSon properties for some manipulation purpose and then writing to a blob . But when I try to using `JToken.Parse` I am getting exception or internal server error.Below is the code I am using:
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req,TextWriter outputBlob,ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    log.LogInformation($"Response is {requestBody}");
    dynamic jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    JToken jCategory = jObject;
    var clus = jCategory["clusters"];

    foreach(JObject item in clus)
    {
        var custom_tag=item["custom_tags"];
        var app_logical_name = item.SelectToken("custom_tags.app_name");
        item.SelectToken("init_scripts_safe_mode").Parent.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("app_logical_name",app_logical_name));
    }              

    var clus2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jCategory,Formatting.None);
    //var clus_new=JArray.Parse(clus).toString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

    outputBlob.Write(clus2);
    // outputBlob.Write(clus_new);

    return new OkObjectResult(requestBody);
}
```

I have tried both ways but both are giving runtime errors. I just need to put the json in a single line(without any formatting) and write to blob.Can you please help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure on my side:

```
{
    "clusters":[
        {
            "custom_tags":{
                "app_name": "appname1"
            },
            "init_scripts_safe_mode":{
                "xxx": "yyy"
            }
        },
        {
            "custom_tags":{
                "app_name": "appname2"
            },
            "init_scripts_safe_mode":{
                "xxx2": "yyy2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "test":"333"
}
```

And this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            log.LogInformation($"Response is {requestBody}");
            dynamic jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            JToken jCategory = jObject;
            var clus = jCategory["clusters"];s2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jCategory, Formatting.None);

            foreach (JObject item in clus)
            {
                var custom_tag = item["custom_tags"];
                var app_logical_name = item.SelectToken("custom_tags.app_name");
                var xxx = item.SelectToken("init_scripts_safe_mode");
                xxx.Parent.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("app_logical_name", app_logical_name));
                log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(custom_tag, Formatting.None));
                log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(app_logical_name, Formatting.None));
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(clus);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems no problem:

[image]

[image]

If you get the server side error, please check the details log to get where is the error comes from.

The 500 error is not helpful to solve this problem, you need to check the specific error of the azure function. You can use application insights to get the details error. The function must configure the corresponding application insights before you can view the log on the portal.

So you need to configure an application insights to your function app like this:

[image]

Then your function app will restart.

Of course, you can also go to kudu to view:

First, go to advanced tools, then click 'GO',

[image]

Then After you go to kudu, click Debug Console -> CMD -> LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> yourtriggername. You will find log file there.

If you are based on linux OS, after go to kudu, just click 'log stream'(this is not supportted to consumption plan for linux.).